# set a range of values to zero using if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do this:

```
A           |   B
```

===================

```
'blank'     |   1

12          |   4   

'blank'     |   2

13          |  'blank'
```

I want to check B column and if there is a number there ( any number ) ,then fill the corresponding A cell (but only blank(empty) A cells )  with zero value.

I am trying something like this:

```
=IF( ISNUMBER(B1:B4)  AND  ( IF( NOT(ISNUMBER(A1:A4) ) ) ); (A1:A4  = 0);""    )
```

but it doesn't work.( I have set to the else statement above the "" )

Comment: are you writing VBA for this or writing simple excel formula? Is this okay if you get these values stored in column C (instead of directly on A) because there are already values populated there?

Comment: You will need another column if you want to just use formulas... Then hide the original "A" column

Comment: @Abdul Hameed:It is just a formula.I want to populate A column.( where is a blank ,not change the already populated values).

Comment: Yes i understand. Is this okay if you do this in column C?

Comment: @Abdul Hameed:As I said I want to do it in column A , but if this is not possible at all,I believe I can create a C column and copy A there.

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: You can't because you're going to have to put a formula anyway and then, you're going to replace what's inside a cell. 
The only way to do without adding a column is to use a small VBA code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy to write formula in new column then use this formula in column C for every cell `C1=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B1),A1=""),0,A1)` then drag this formula for `C2, C3, C4 etc.,`.

[my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppSGM.jpg)